# Nuxtjs and Firebase Auth: await firebase.auth().currentUser not waiting?

Tags: firebase, vuejs2, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js

Nuxt.js is focuses on server side rendering and has an `asyncData` property  that is called once before the page component is loaded.

I am trying something like:

```js
async asyncData({params}) {
    // firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{ // <-- this doesn't work in the asyncData property
      let user = await firebase.auth().currentUser
      let info = {}
      console.log(user)

      user.uid === null // true
}
```

Two similar questions:

- [firebase.auth().currentUser is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887044/firebase-auth-currentuser-is-null)
- [Get firebase.auth().currentUser with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43821921/get-firebase-auth-currentuser-with-async-await)

have solutions which do not seem to work with nuxt...

I have also tried:

```js
function getCurrentUser(auth) {

  let userLoaded = false;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     if (userLoaded) {
          resolve(firebase.auth().currentUser);
     }
     const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        userLoaded = true;
        unsubscribe();
        resolve(user);
     }, reject);
  });
}
```

Comment: I think the problem comes from the fact that `onAuthStateChanged` does not return a promise but **adds an observer** for changes to the user's sign-in state, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged

Comment: @RenaudTarnec yeah, which is why I also tried without it... I have also wrapped `currentUser` in a promise and it doesnt work

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same thing. Any updates?

Comment: I believe it doesn't work that way. asyncData() is run in server side when loading for the first time. There won't be any currentUser instance in server side. It's only available in the client side.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `onAuthStateChanged` is triggered on client-side only. But the thing is, *SSR* functionality would make sense only for non-authenticated users, for authed-user scenario might as well just put the firebase call logic into `mounted` hook.